# Issue in handling image and table side by side in two column IEEE format

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, two-column

I want to add image and table side by side with different caption in **two column format** document of **IEEE** and I tried with this thing but it not working like that for me. Either the caption of table is up or caption of image is below. I want to align caption of image and table in same area.

```
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{figure}
\CenterFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox
  {\begin{tabular}{|P{1cm}|P{1.2cm}|P{1.2cm}|}
    \hline
    Steps & MR Execution Time in Seconds & CC Execution Time in Seconds \\ \hline
    1   & 8 & 6   \\ \hline
    2   & 8 & 7    \\ \hline
    3   & 8 & 9    \\ \hline
    4   & 8 & 7    \\ \hline
    5   & 8 & 7    \\ \hline
    6   & 8 & 8    \\ \hline
    7   & 8 & 7    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }
{\caption{Step-Wise Performance}\label{tab:test}}
\killfloatstyle
\ffigbox
  {\caption{Step-Wise Performance}}
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{CG}}

\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

As you can see below image right side has table and image together but it has some problem in alignment so please help me in fix it.

[image: It is an image of above compiled file of latex]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and complete your code so that we have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Something we can copy-paste-compile makes it a lot easier to help. You can use images from the `mwe` package, so people already have them.